# How to grant web app access to restricted file?

Tags: macos, permission

I am running a Tomcat server via Eclipse.

I have a restricted file that contains information the web application running on Tomcat needs to perform its duties.

I understand how to grant/deny access to regular users, but how to for this web app?

Info:

- Macbook Pro 10.7.5 (Lion)
- Tomcat 7
- Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions on OS X are very similar to unix, so you could just make the file and folder readable by the user that you have chosen to run Tomcat.

Finder Information lets you change things as well as `chown` and `chmod` from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is discover which user owns the Tomcat process. You can do this by typing `ps axu -w` at the command line. The owner of the process will be in the first column. On a standard Mac install the web server (the process called `httpd`) is owned by the user `_www`. I assume Tomcat is owned by the same user.

Now change the ownership of the file so it is owned by _www and then you will be fine. Do this `chown _www filename` replacing filename of course.

Once you've done that you should be right.